# compact oriented $4k$-manifold-> euler characteristic is congruent to the signature mod $2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, duality-theorems

Let $M$ be a compact oriented $4k$-manifold, $\chi_M$ the euler characteristic of $M$ and $sig(M)$ the signature of $M$. Why is $\chi_M \equiv sig(M)$ mod $2$?

In the book " a concise course in algebraic topology" from J.P. May on page 166/167 there is a proof which I don't understand and which is very short. I will repeat the proof here:

It is $sig(M)=r-s$, where $r+s=dim H^{2k}(M;\mathbb{R})\equiv \chi_M$ mod $2$.

I only understand that it is $sig(M)=r-s$ with $r+s=dim H^{2k}(M;\mathbb{R})$.  But everything else I don't understand. Could you explain me the proof or do you have an other idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Poincare duality the Betti numbers for cohomology groups of complementary dimensions all cancel if one works modulo 2.  That leaves one with the middle dimension $2k$.  Again working modulo 2, one has $r+s=r-s$, whence the result.

Comment: ok, thanks your your answer. I still try to understand "By Poincare duality the Betti numbers for cohomology groups of complementary dimensions all cancel if one works modulo 2". I know that $H^j(M;\mathbb{R})\cong H_{4k-j}((M;\mathbb{R})$ (this is the Poincare-version which I saw in lecture). And now you say the dimension of the cohomology groups are all even except the one in dimension 2k, or what do you mean?

Comment: ahh.. now I know what you mean!